# A Sybase stored procedure runs faster the second time it is run

Tags: sql, performance, sybase

I have one stored procedure in sybase which is taking more time for the first run than for runs directly after.

While creating this stored procedure, I am using `with recompile` option.  So it shouldn't save any plan for the stored procedure.  It will create new plan everytime the procedure executes.

Why would a stored procedure run faster the second time it is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because of sybase internal cache.
So the first time stored the relevant data in the cache and that's why the second time is faster.

You can check with `sp_helpcache` to see what's configured.

Comment: while creating stored procedure i am using with recompile option. so it wont save any plan for sp. it will create new plan everytime the procedure executes.

Comment: There are different types of cache: `Procedure cache` and `Data cache`. You are right that the `procedure cache` will not be used and a new plan will be created, BUT the `data cache` still can be used and it might be that the index or tables are cached on the second time.